# How to improve UITableView performance when have a lot of images?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

Here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"custom";

    SampleTableCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[SampleTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    User *user = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

    cell.name_Label.text = user.event_name;
    cell.description_Label.text = user.event_description;
    cell.venue_Label.text = user.event_venue;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                   [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Here is my delegate method for getting data:

```
-(void)repaint:(NSMutableArray *)retrievedData
{
    if (retrievedData.count > 0)
    {
        userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];

        for (userObj in retrievedData)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@is the value",retrievedData);

            url_Img1=@"http://kiascenehai.pk/assets/uploads/event-images/50x50-thumb/";
            url_Img2=userObj.event_dpURL;
            url_Img_FULL = [url_Img1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:url_Img2];
            [arr addObject:url_Img_FULL];
            NSUserDefaults * userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [userDefault setObject:userObj.event_dpURL forKey:@"dpURL"];
            [userDefault synchronize];
        result = [userDefault objectForKey:@"dpURL"];
        NSLog(@"Show url_Img_FULL: %@",url_Img_FULL);
        [tableData addObjectsFromArray:retrievedData];
        [table reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: when i scroll table ; it shows jerks when loads new cells.I need some way to improve its scrolling like facebook app.

Comment: u should use the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) Library.. It will make your tableview really smooth. i've used it myself in a lot of apps..

Comment: Ahmed Z.But i am not able to using it..I am new to ios development and its going above my mind ..Need some other idea

Comment: THere is no other idea or way to make it smoother…

Answer (score 1):

Many Third party source codes for Available for Lazy image loading in iOS:

Check the below URL:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

It must help for you.

Comment: is there any other faster way to like using some option from storyboard or code a little ; as i had created all project and it is going to cross its dead line

Comment: Its very simple. You can use This lazy image loading in All UITableView, UICollectionView and UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Olivier Poitrey**
we can use [sdwebimage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). 
it will use to get images asynchronously and also you can cache the image. hope it will help

> How To Use
>
> API documentation is available at CocoaDocs - SDWebImage
>
> Using UIImageView+WebCache category with UITableView
>
> Just #import the UIImageView+WebCache.h header, and call the
>   setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: method from the
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: UITableViewDataSource method.
>   Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching
>   management.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
> 
> ...
> 
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>     static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
> 
>     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
> 
>     if (cell == nil)
>     {
>         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
>                                        reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
>     }
> 
>     // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
>     [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
>                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
> 
>     cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
>     return cell; }
```

Using blocks

> With blocks, you can be notified about the image download progress and
>   whenever the image retrival has completed with success or not:
>
> // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the
>   web image

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL
> URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
>                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
>                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {... completion code here ...}];
```

Note:

> neither your success nor failure block will be call if your image
>   request is canceled before completion.
>
> Using SDWebImageManager
>
> The SDWebImageManager is the class behind the UIImageView+WebCache
>   category. It ties the asynchronous downloader with the image cache
>   store. You can use this class directly to benefit from web image
>   downloading with caching in another context than a UIView (ie: with
>   Cocoa).
>
> Here is a simple example of how to use SDWebImageManager:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
> [manager downloadWithURL:imageURL
>                  options:0
>                  progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
>                  {
>                      // progression tracking code
>                  }
>                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
>                  {
>                      if (image)
>                      {
>                          // do something with image
>                      }
>                  }];
```

Using Asynchronous Image Downloader Independently

> It's also possible to use the async image downloader independently:

```
[SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
>                                                     options:0
>                                                    progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
>                                                    {
>                                                        // progression tracking code
>                                                    }
>                                                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
>                                                    {
>                                                        if (image && finished)
>                                                        {
>                                                            // do something with image
>                                                        }
>                                                    }];
```

Using Asynchronous Image Caching Independently

> It is also possible to use the aync based image cache store
>   independently. SDImageCache maintains a memory cache and an optional
>   disk cache. Disk cache write operations are performed asynchronous so
>   it doesn't add unnecessary latency to the UI.
>
> The SDImageCache class provides a singleton instance for convenience
>   but you can create your own instance if you want to create separated
>   cache namespace.
>
> To lookup the cache, you use the queryDiskCacheForKey:done: method. If
>   the method returns nil, it means the cache doesn't currently own the
>   image. You are thus responsible for generating and caching it. The
>   cache key is an application unique identifier for the image to cache.
>   It is generally the absolute URL of the image.

```
 SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc]
> initWithNamespace:@"myNamespace"]; [imageCache
> queryDiskCacheForKey:myCacheKey done:^(UIImage *image) {
>     // image is not nil if image was found }];
```

By default SDImageCache will lookup the disk cache if an image can't be found in the memory

> cache. You can prevent this from happening by calling the alternative
>   method imageFromMemoryCacheForKey:.
>
> To store an image into the cache, you use the storeImage:forKey:
>   method:

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:myImage
> forKey:myCacheKey];
```

By default, the image will be stored in memory

> cache as well as on disk cache (asynchronously). If you want only the
>   memory cache, use the alternative method storeImage:forKey:toDisk:
>   with a negative third argument.
>
> Using cache key filter
>
> Sometime, you may not want to use the image URL as cache key because
>   part of the URL is dynamic (i.e.: for access control purpose).
>   SDWebImageManager provides a way to set a cache key filter that takes
>   the NSURL as input, and output a cache key NSString.
>
> The following example sets a filter in the application delegate that
>   will remove any query-string from the URL before to use it as a cache
>   key:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>     SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.cacheKeyFilter:^(NSURL *url)
>     {
>         url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:url.scheme host:url.host path:url.path] autorelease];
>         return [url absoluteString];
>     };
> 
>     // Your app init code...
>     return YES; }
```

Comment: how can i use sdwebimage; actually i ma not familiar with this term and i have very short time

Comment: there is document available in this github link you can study that.

Comment: is there any other simple or fast way to improve its performance.like table do not dequeue its cells and load all data

Comment: when you are getting images from server it is heavy operation you have to call it async way and yes reuseability definitely help you but still it will load cell first time and first time there will lag.